# What is the use of getsetdescriptor and memberdescriptor?

Tags: python, descriptor

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismemberdescriptor) only says:

> getsets are attributes defined in extension modules via PyGetSetDef structures. For Python implementations without such types, this method will always return False.
>
> Member descriptors are attributes defined in extension modules via PyMemberDef structures. For Python implementations without such types, this method will always return False.

But I still don't know how to use it. Is there any object in the standard library which belongs to these two categories?

Comment: From the `types.py` source: `GetSetDescriptorType = type(FunctionType.__code__)` and `MemberDescriptorType = type(FunctionType.__globals__)` if this helps

Comment: I'm not sure about the getset descriptors, but I can provide info on `member_descriptor()`, which `types` provides strictly for comparison. So basically, if you've ever used `__slots__` and played around with meta programming, `__slots__` used in `object.__new__()` or `type.__new__()` prevents the creation of `__dict__` and `__weakref__` in instances, while any names given in `__slots__` are used in the creation of `member_descriptor` objects supplied to the class `__dict__`. Hope that helps clear up some confusion. ;)

Comment: I don't know how to explicitly create `member_descriptor.__new__( PyTypeObject *type, PyMemberDef *member )` objects, as I'm sure you've already found out you can't just initialize them... I stumbled here looking for that answer as I can't inherit from the class containing the descriptors I need... But if you look in descrobject.c in Py27's source, you'll find the related information I'm referencing from.